# ibm cognos transformer multiple fact table not supported by dimension

Tags: cognos-10, transformer-model

i'm actually working on a solution that have two fact tables, and i need to add one more fact table
so the etl work fine
i add my new table to the pack in ibm framework manager , and i make relations between my fact table and other tables "tables that are used for dimensions in transformer"
i make some tests in framework manager the relations are goud 
[test relation between the fact table and the dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FQbK.jpg)

when i create the cube i cant find aggregation between dimensions and my  new fact table it give the total sum of my fact table.
when i search suported  data sources in dimension i realize that the my fact table  is not supported by the dimensions
[my fact table not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AePXc.jpg)
i dont know how to make that relation in transformer......

any help

sincerely

hope you have a goud day